# How to check if current user is a Workspace Admin in the Asana API?

Tags: asana, asana-api

I am working on managing user access to workspaces via the API. [Cleaning inactive users], and am running into issues where I can authenticate the user, but don't have a way to check if the user is a workspace admin.

This becomes an issue because I am authenticating the user, and then managing users in a later step.  I would like to show an error when the user authenticates if they are able to manage users on the chosen workspace.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently is not an endpoint to determine if a user is an admin. I do think this would be helpful, and I will surface it with our API team.

There are endpoints that can only be accessed by admins, such as [user management](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/workspaces#user-mgmt).  Unfortunately, I don't think this solves your requirements.

Comment: I'd like to let the user know on authentication if the account has the permissions needed to do user management.  Is there a read-only admin endpoint I could use to check this?